# How can I retain update bindings while showing additional information?

Tags: linq-to-sql, data-binding, .net-3.5, datagridview

I'd like to display a linq-to-sql on a datagridview as such:

```
 Dim myQ = From b In _dcBooks.Books Select New With {Key b.ID, b.Title, b.Genre, b.ISBN, b.Format, b.Series, _
            .Author =b.BooksAuthors.Count()}
```

the formula for the authors column is simplified as it would normally display nothing, the only author or "multiple".

When I add this column the automatic updates that the following query implements don't work:

```
Dim myQ=from b in _dcBooks.Books select b
```

Is it possible to retain the automatic updates/deletes with additional query induced columns like this or is there a simple way to put them in my code?

I can read C# or vb so answers in either is ok by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up having to wrap everything in an intermediate class that stores the row along with properties that can display or change the row's value when changed. So a custom shim object is needed for every single custom display I guess.